# Swift2: mathematical operations with Int64 and Int32?

Tags: math, swift2

What is the right way to deal with an operation that involves both a Int64 and an Int32 in Swift? For example, the following fails with "Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int32' and 'Int64'":

```
let i64 : Int64 = 1
let i32 : Int32 = 1
let val = i32 / i64
```

The simple scenario here works:

```
let i64 : Int64 = 1
let i32 : Int32 = 1
let val = Int64(i32) / i64
```

Now my 'real world' case is, which fails with "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int64' with an argument list of type '(Int32)'":

```
let timedMetadataGroup : AVMutableTimedMetadataGroup
// timedMetadataGroup is initialised with values from another function
let startSecs = timedMetadataGroup.timeRange.start.value.value / Int64(timedMetadataGroup.timeRange.start.timescale.value)
```

What is different between the pure case and the the above case? How would I resolve this? Is there more than one type of Int32 or Int64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing

```
timedMetadataGroup.timeRange.start.timescale.value
```

but the type of `timescale` is `CMTimeScale` which is an alias for `Int32`. So I think you should just stop to timescale and remove the `.value` part.

```
let startSecs = timedMetadataGroup.timeRange.start.value / Int64(timedMetadataGroup.timeRange.start.timescale)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't allow mathematical operations with values of different types.